# OpenSSL - LNK 2019

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm getting LNK 2019 when trying to link in the OpenSSL libraries for a project I'm working on. I compiled the OpenSSL libraries and ran the test and all of them passed. I played with openssl.exe and got it to correctly create and MD5 hash. When I try to use the functions provided by the API though, it just won't recognize them. I even used dumpbin -headers on the .lib files to make sure that the ones I was using contained the correct references for the functions I was using.

I made sure to include the correct files and paths (I also included the header which isn't pictured here).

[image]

Here are the actual files and their paths

[image]

Here's the actual errors.

[image]

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_MD_CTX_create referenced in function _main
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_DigestInit_ex referenced in function _main
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OpenSSL_add_all_digests
>   referenced in function _main error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _EVP_get_digestbyname referenced in function _main error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals

How do I fix this? Did I put the files in the right place or did I forget an include? I've spent a few days trying to fix this already, this is my last resort :/

Im using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012

Comment: It certainly looks like you're including the proper libs and locations. Something else must be missing. The only other thing you should include in your question is the version of VS you're using, btw. I'll have to try this just for the curiosity sake.

Comment: Commands and error messages should be posted here, not in external sites. Otherwise the question has no permanent value here. -1

Comment: Just seemed easier to get pictures instead of describing everything that I was doing (no one ever reads when I explain in that much detail).
They were originally pictures but I didn't have the rep for it. Adding the errors under the picture though.

Comment: No-one will ever read it if you don't put it here. Don't make it even harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was building for x86 when I should have been building with x64. As the x64 option did not show up in the menu, I thought it was unavailable to me. I realized that I had to add it under the project properties and now everything works fine.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be problem with calling conventions.

Please check the project setting regarding calling convention.

OpenSSL compiles with /Gd option that means function will be of __cdecl calling convention.

You can either change your calling convention to /Gd or prefix OpenSSL function signatures which you are using with __cdecl.

I believe that this might help. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx) explains how to change calling convention.

Please confirm if this can help you.

Comment: I will be able to try this out at work tomorrow morning. (approx 8 hours)

Comment: It seems I am already using this calling convention and I figured out my problem.